# Custom binding for multiple selection in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to create custom binding in knockout to use it as multiple selection field. For example:
I want to design selection screen for invoice report. On this selection screen I would like to use field 'Invoice Type' to allow users to provide only the types of invoices, they are interested in. If I use standard text box for this field, users would be allowed only to provide one invoice type. I want them to be able to provide more than one type in selection.
My idea was to prepare a binding such as:

```
// html
<input data-bind="multiple: { data: optionsArray }" />
...
// view  model
optionsArray = ko.observableArray();
```

where I could provide field 'optionsArray', which would hold the multiple choise of users (in my case that would be multiple invoice types).
If it comes to UI, I thought it could look like this: there's a button next to the element with multiple binding. After clicking it, dialog window appears and all the 'optionsArray' elements are displayed there and can be changed, new can be added or deleted.

I don't know how to achieve this because I failed on the part of displaying all the optionsArray elements in dialog box in a way they can be edited as observables and all the changes are reflected in viewModel.optionsArray. Is this even possible?

Do you have any experience in building custom bindings and help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create `custom binding` for that. You can use `selectedOptions` binding here is link to the documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html.

Add `optionsArray` and `selectedTypes` observable arrays to your view model:

```
self.optionsArray = ko.observableArray();
self.selectedTypes = ko.observableArray();
```

And bind to `multiselect`:

```
<select data-bind="options: optionsArray, selectedOptions: selectedTypes" size="5" multiple="true"></select>
```

Here is working example with dialog and adding new options: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/nZtZd/

Comment: This is good, but select element is not so stylable and the most important I would like to edit each item in place.

Comment: @Eori What? The select element is a native HTML element: it can be styled by CSS to the same level as every other HTML element.

Comment: The native multi-select is pretty horrible though, styling only gets you so far. A lot of apps have a dropdown of items which can be added to a text area. Sometimes this is done with a hidden multi-select to pass the selections to the server. This is the kind of thing knockout should excel at.

Answer (score 0):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.multiple = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
         $(element).change(function () {
             var actualValueArray = $(this).val().split(",");
             valueAccessor(actualValueArray);
         });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var valueArray = valueAccessor();
        var valueArrayUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value); 
        // Join all invoice numbers using comma
        $(element).val(valueArrayUnwrapped.join(", "))
    }
};
```

Comment: This is just taking all the array elements and displaying them. I would like to bind inside the multiple binding each array element to a different input element so they could be editable.

Comment: In this case just create template not custom binding like described in Editable Grid example http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html

Comment: Ok, but if I have 20 such fields in one view, that's a lot of code. It would be much neater and cleaner to have it as a binding.

Comment: Did you consider creating template (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) for that arrays?